# mongo db date range query (between date range)

Tags: php, mongodb, date

i want to find records which are between  "startdate" & "enddate". i get this record for date like "2013-05-22", "2013-05-20","2013-05-10","2013-05-05" etc.

my fields in collection are as below :

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("518221f16541b9980d000002"),
  'userId' => '2d40981c83a37e758ced05dc325e40fa',
  'kpiId' => 'f516ed1c59e6b310c47cdfc06abb17aa',
  'dateOpt' => 'customize',
  'startDate' => '2013-05-02',
  'endDate' => '2013-05-22',
  'personalTarget' => '',
  'assignedTarget' => '100000.00',
  'singleTargetAmt' => 6666.6666666667,
  'createdOn' => '2013-05-02 13:51:05',
  'updatedOn' => '2013-05-02 13:51:05',
  'distributionMethod' => 'manual',
)
```

and my query is :

```
  array(
    "kpiId" => 'f516ed1c59e6b310c47cdfc06abb17aa',
        "userId" => '2d40981c83a37e758ced05dc325e40fa',
        "startDate" => array
            (
                '$gte' => '2013-05-03'
            ),
    "endDate" => array
            (
                '$lte' => '2013-05-03'
            )      
    )
```

it gives no records. my query is wrong ?

Comment: Are the fields in your documents really string and not date objects?

Comment: I have noticed that that document won't be found, are you sure you have any document that are on the `03-05-2013`? If you tried `2013-05-02` instead do you get results?

Comment: for 02-05-2013 i don't get result. i want results for all dates between 02-05-2013 and 22-05-2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.elemMatch(
Criteria.where("startDate").lte(date)
.and("endDate").gte(date)
);
```

Comment: i have two different fields and one date value for query. created date may differ it is "2013-04-25" if i created this record on 25th april so its not work.

Comment: He has got the right syntax for PHP, plus that isn't PHP syntax there

Comment: @priyankapatel try something like above.

Comment: Plus he doesn't need $elemMatch here since the two fields are in the root document, and what's b?